# Can I use the fridge still without plumbing in water,model Electrolux ERES31800W

Tags: refrigerator

Can I still use the fridge on model Electrolux ERES31800W,without having to plumb in the water?

Comment: What does the owner's manual say?

Answer (score 7):

In general, plumbing water to a fridge is only required in order to use the ice maker and water dispensing features. You can use it as a fridge with just electricity connected.

Typically, there is an easy way to shut off the ice maker. If you don't have water connected you should do that in order to reduce possible wear on electric valves and other parts. You may also be able to disconnect and temporarily remove the ice maker so you can use the space it would take for other purposes.

Comment: Many modern refrigerators also use water to provide moisture to the vegetable drawer or hydrator.  I don't specifically know  about OP's model.